# Entering array values into database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm using the code below to enter the selected array values into my database, depending on which country they select.

```
 $Location = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location'], $Link);

 MYSQL_Query ("INSERT INTO users(location)VALUES('$Location')");

 $countries = array(
    "AF" => "Afghanistan",
    "UK" => "United Kingdom",
    "US" => "United States",
    "AS" => "American Samoa", //etc..
    echo '<select name="location">'; 

  foreach($countries as $countrycode =>$country) { 
  echo '<option value="' . $countrycode. '">' . $country . '</option>'; 
    } 
  echo '</select>';
```

Everything is working fine except in my MySQL database the value's being stored are the `$countrycode`
So it's saving as UK for United Kingdom, I want it to save as United Kingdom instead. Where am I going wrong?

PS; I have the full country list if anyone would like it, kind regards, Shanie.

EDIT: Issue solved!
Replaced `'<option value="' . $countrycode. '">' . $country . '</option>';`
 with `'<option value="' . $country. '">' . $country . '</option>';`

Thanks to Chris.

Comment: Please keep in mind `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Please migrate to PDO.

Comment: Maybe `$location` should be `$countries[$_POST['location']]` and move up the `$countries` array to the top ?

Comment: Your code is very vulnerable to sql injections. Please use prepared statements instead of string concatenations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `value` of the `option` to the `name`, not the `code`.

```
<option value="' . $country. '">' . $country . '</option>';
```

Otherwise it is the code.

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

> The content of this attribute represents the value to be submitted with the form, should this option be selected. If this attribute is omitted, the value is taken from the text content of the option element.

Comment: You are a time saver! Thank you Chris, I really appreciate your response.